# How to unit test an abstract class using Microsft Fakes framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, pex

I have the following abstract class for which I want to write a unit test. I am new to Microsoft Fakes and so far I have only used it for testing public classes.

```
public abstract class ProvideBase 
{
    private string tag = string.Empty;

    public string Tag
    {
        get { return tag; }         
        set { tag = value; }
    }

}

public static String GetMyConfig(string sectionName)
{
    MyConfiguration config = MyConfiguration.GetConfig(sectionName);
    return config.GetMyConfig(config.DefaultConfig);
}
```

I wrote a unit test for my `GetMyConfig()` method. My test coverage is not 100% however, since I have not used the `Tag` property.  Is there a way I can test it to?

Pex does some kind of mocking to test such things. How do I mock/test the `Tag` property using Microsoft Fakes?

Comment: 100% test coverage is not that important. You don't need to test that every simple property returns the value that you just set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you want to use Fakes for this.  Deriving a class from it makes it easy enough to test:

```
class TestableProvideBase : ProvideBase{}

[TestMethod]
public void TestTagProperty() {
    var sut = new TestableProvideBase();

    Assert.AreEqual(String.Empty, sut.Tag);

    sut.Tag = "someValue";

    Assert.AreEqual("someValue", sut.Tag);
}
```